# how to change background color of seizer path

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have unbutton  as below,

```
    taskBtn=[[PNTButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,app.screenwidth,app.screenheight/2)];
    [taskBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [taskBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(taskBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:taskBtn];
```

i have drawn a triangle using beizerpath on task button ,when user clicks on triangle i need to change  change the background color of triangle but i was unable to change background color.its giving error as:

`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

can anyone help me how to change background color of beizerpath triangle when user clicks on it.

Comment: please add the code for taskBtnClicked method

Comment: UIBezierPath *path = [[PNTUtility sharedUtility] bezierPathForButton:self];  if ([path containsPoint:point])                                   {                       [[[PNTUtility sharedUtility] colorForButton:self] setFill];
//    [path fill];
        }   in colorer button method i set the color

Comment: The error speaks for itself. invalid context 0x0. Your CGContext is nil. Without looking at the code it's hard to tell what the issue is.